# How do I arrange the text on the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone could help me with an issue I'm having. I wanted the text "Liam's Digital Portfolio" to be in the centre of the webpage at the top in line with the navigation bar text. In addition, I then wanted the navigation bar to be on the far right hand corner as shown within the codepen link http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/qRowVK.

I have only started programming and this is my second day and really want to improve, apologies if the code is not in the correct structure.

Below is my HTML code, within the codepen is my CSS if needed.

```
<div id="Navagationbar">
   <ul>
  <li><b><a href="#">HomePage</a></b></li>
  <li><b><a href="#">Portfolio</a></b></li>
  <li><b><a href="#">Contact Us</a></b></li>
  <li><b><center>Liam's Digital Portfolio<center></b></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Liam.

Comment: center tag is deprecated, so alternatives are suggested. If you'd like to have certain text as centered, and apart from the rest of the list, it's probably the best to treat it as a separate element.

Comment: @Armin Ok, thanks for the feedback. What do you mean by deprecated? Can you show me what you mean by separate element please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center Here you have some explanation. By separate element I meant not <li> element, but some non-list element, outside of the list. You can check L L's answer for more details.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please take a moment to review our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish you all the best with your coding journey :) I will give you an easy solution to get the desired effect. First off, cut the padding-top from the body in the css:

```
padding-top: 180px;
```

Now from your html, remove

```
  <li><b><center>Liam's Digital Portfolio<center></b></li>
```

Since this is your page title, it is standard practice to have it inside of h1 tags. Then we can center it with simple css. The html will look like this:

```
<h1 class="title">Liam's Digital Portfolio</h1>       

<div id="Navagationbar">
 <ul>
  <li><b><a href="#">HomePage</a></b></li>
  <li><b><a href="#">Portfolio</a></b></li>
  <li><b><a href="#">Contact Us</a></b></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And now we can simply add this to the css

```
.title{text-align:center;}
```

With the padding-top removed and this added, the title will be in the center of the page inline with the navigation bar. I see you have a lot of issues with your css so I suggest you go through a good tutorial, like this one from w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/css/ . I hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Fantastic answer! I appreciate your help. I will look into using the website you recommend to improve/learn my coding skills.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can also search youtube as it has a lot of good css tutorials if you find it more effective to watch someone explain it to you rather than just read text.

Comment: The pen looks like it's the same as the first one you sent me. Here is one following the instructions I've written above http://codepen.io/lukaphp/pen/zNWQWb . The title is in the center inline with the navigation bar

Comment: No problem, I sorted the issue. I will send you the completed website when it's done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make the HTML changes as below

```
        <ul>
          <li><b><a href="#">HomePage</a></b></li>
          <li><b><a href="#">Portfolio</a></b></li>
          <li><b><a href="#">Contact Us</a></b></li>
          <li style="position:absolute;right:45%"><b><a href="#">Liam's Digital Portfolio</a></b></li>
       </ul>
```

CSS changes as below

```
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



    h1 {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:white;
    font-size:10pt;
    text-align:center;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color:grey;
}

   #Navagationbar {
   font-family:Arial;
   color:white;
   font-size:10pt;
   text-align:center;

}

   #Navagationbar ul {
   list-style:none;
   float:right;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;

}
   #Navagationbar ul li {
   display:block;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;


}

#Navagationbar ul li a {
   display:block;
   margin:0 0 0 1px;
   padding:3px 10px;
   color:white;;
   text-decoration:none;
   line-height:1.3em;

}
#Navagationbar ul li a:hover {
   color:white;
}
#Navagationbar ul li a.active,
#Navagationbar ul li a.active:hover {
   color:white;

}

body {
  margin:0;
}
.page{
  min-height:-590px;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, #999, #FFF);
}
#footer{
  list-style:none inside none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#1f1f1f;
  font-size:0;
}
#footer li {
  font-family:Arial;
  float: right;
  color:white;
  font-size:10pt;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  height:50px;
  padding:0 20px;
  line-height:3.3;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
  border-left:1px solid #333;
}
#footer li {
  font-family:Arial;
  float: left;
  color:white;
  font-size:10pt;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  height:50px;
  padding:0 20px;
  line-height:3.3;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
  border-left:1px solid #333;
}


#footer li:last-child {
  border-right:0;
}

    body {
        background:url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/34088/pexels-photo.jpg');
            position:static;
            height:400px; 
            background-attachment:fixed;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-size:cover;

        }
```